# Setting Server Ip Address in React Native for android

Tags: android, react-native

In debug build we can set the server IP address and port through dev settings option on shaking of device or clicking menu button in android.

**I want to know, how to set server IP address dynamically for production build in android?** as we cannot get the setting menu for setting the Ip address and port number in release builds.

Comment: `or clicking menu button `. Why cant you do that in release? And what do you mean with `dev settings option`?? ?

Comment: In release build we don't see setting dialog which appears after clicking menu button in android. After releasing my app I can't tell the user to click menu button and set the Ip and port address. I want to know how to set the IP address dyanmically from code?

Comment: If it is your app and your app needs to connect to a server then i do not unerstand that you dont let the user allow to input a server ip and port then. Moreover you did not tell about which menu button you are talking. I find this all very vague.

Comment: But if this is a 'React Native' feature i better not comment.

Comment: Yes it is react native feature

Comment: We cannot set IP Address dynamically in production build as we are generating bundle file for production build.